# Maximize $abc$ on $a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca=1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

> Find the maximum value  of $abc$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and satisfy $$a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca=1.$$

[Here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/626350837/answer/3253314861) is a solution by a Chinses answerer.

WLOG, assume $a>0$ and $bc>0$. Denote the sum $b+c$ by $\theta$. Then we can obtain

\begin{align*} 1&=a^2+(b+c)^2-bc+a(b+c)\\[8pt] &\ge a^2+(b+c)^2-\left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2+a(b+c)\\[8pt] &=a^2+\frac{3}{4}\theta^2+a\theta\\[8pt]  &\ge a^2+\frac{3}{4}\theta^2-\left(\frac{2}{3}a^2+\frac{3}{8}\theta^2\right)\\[8pt]  &=\frac{a^2}{3}+\frac{3}{16}\theta^2+\frac{3}{16}\theta^2\\[8pt]  &\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{256}a^2\theta^4} ,\end{align*}

which implies $$a\theta^2\le \frac{16}{9}.$$Therefore, $$abc\le a\left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2=\frac{a\theta^2}{4}\le \frac{4}{9}.$$

**Is it correct? Any other better solutions?**

Comment: $uvw$ kills it immediately. I'll post my solution later. Very busy now

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2,$ where $v^2$ may be negative and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to find a minimum of the following expression:
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ab)}{\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}$$ or
$$\frac{9u^2-3v^2}{w^2},$$ which decreases as function of $v^2$, which  says that it's enough to solve our problem for a maximal value of $v^2$, which by $uvw$ says that it's enough to check an equality case of two variables.

Let $b=c=1$ and $a=-\frac{3}{2}.$

Thus, we obtain a value $\sqrt[3]{\frac{81}{16}}.$

But $$\frac{a^2+2a+3}{\sqrt[3]{a^2}}\geq\sqrt[3]{\frac{81}{16}}$$ it's
$$(2a+3)^2(4a^4+12a^3+39a^2+32a+48)\geq0,$$ which is obvious and we got a maximal value of $w^2$, which is   $\sqrt[3]{\frac{16}{81}},$ which gives $$abc=w^3\leq\frac{4}{9}.$$

Comment: 1. $a$ can be negative.  How do you prove $4a^4+12a^3+39a^2+32a+48>0$ ? 2. $v^2$ may be negative ,then what is the point to write $v^2$ instead of $v $ ? If $v^2<0$ so you are wrong to say that which decreases as function of $v^2$ .

Comment: @User What do you say? Let $v^2=x$. So $f(x)=-x$ decreases. Do you agree?

Comment: $v^2=-(x^2+1)$ then the function is strictly increasing.

Comment: In your example I don't see any relation with my solution. We say about a function $f(x)=\frac{9u^2-3x}{w^2}.$  $u^2\geq0,$ $w^2>0$. From here $f$ decreases.

Comment: $v^2$ **may be negative** Let $v^2=-(x^2+1)$

Comment: @User Yes, of course! You did not see decreasing functions with maybe negative variables? See better the function $f(x)=\frac{9u^2-3x}{w^2}$ or it's the same $f(v^2)=\frac{9u^2-3v^2}{w^2}.$

Comment: Why $v^2$ instead of $v$ ? I got wrong your function at first

Comment: @User Because  we say about the function of $v^2$. See please better my post. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: You don't understand me. Why $ab+bc+ac=v^2$ instead of $v$ ? You say that $v^2<0$ . Why ?

Comment: @User For homogeneous. The expression $ab+ac+bc$ is a polynomial of second  degree and $v^2$ is a second degree.